# Moving pipes query in a Flappy Bird game

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

I am trying to build a Flappy Bird like game in Adobe Flash, using Action Script 3 as a school project. I am using an array of Pipe objects to create the number of Pipes for each level (at this stage my code is with one level/stage).

I have one problem though, after I created the array of Pipes and them added each Pipe object to the stage, I tried to use other function to move the pipes, iterating through the array and changing  the x dimension value to every Pipe object, but it doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

stop();
Bird_mc.stop();
//array of pipes;
var pipeArray:Vector.<Pipe >  = new Vector.<Pipe >   ;

var birdVelocity:int = 0;
var stageGravity:int = 2;

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,birdFall);
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,createPipesAndLines);
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,movePipesAndLines);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,birdFly);

function birdFall(event:Event):void
{
    Bird_mc.y +=  birdVelocity;
    birdVelocity +=  stageGravity;
}

function birdFly(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    birdVelocity = -16;
    Bird_mc.play();
}

/*Move Pipes and Lines to the left - TO BE MADE*/
function createPipesAndLines(event:Event):void
{
    for (var i:int = 0; i<10; i++)
    {   //use of of-else to separate the pipes up and down and rotate em
        if (i%2==0)
        {
            pipeArray.push(new Pipe());
            addChild(pipeArray[i]);
            pipeArray[i].x = i * 250;
            pipeArray[i].y = 50;
        }
        else
        {
            var tempPipe:Pipe = new Pipe();
            tempPipe.rotation = 180;
            pipeArray.push(tempPipe);

            addChild(pipeArray[i]);
            pipeArray[i].x = i * 300;
            pipeArray[i].y = 400;
        }
    }
}
//move the pipes to left
function movePipesAndLines(event:Event):void
{
    for (var i:int = 0; i<10; i++)
    {
        pipeArray[i].x -=  0.5;

    }
}
```

Comment: Your biggest problem here is that `birdFall`, `createPipesAndLines`, and `movePipesAndLines` are being called **every** enter_frame. Place a `trace` inside each of your functions and see how often they are called. You may want to consider creating your pipes and lines in one frame, then in the next frame perform the movement. You will need to rethink birdFall though. It really should be a flag that is checked on each enter_frame.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I'd recommend having a single event function that calls every other function that need updating.

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);

function loop(event:Event):void {
    birdFall();
    birdFly();
    movePipesAndLines();
}
```

Secondly you don't really want to add all pipes from the start of the game. I would imagine *Flappy Bird* attaches new **Pipe** objects as the screen moves. It's a whole lot more efficient that way.

Other than that the code looks good. I would however like to see what's inside the **Pipe** object. Perhaps Pipe.**x** is an **int** instead of **Number**?